# AngularJS's filter - performance clarification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've [*read*](http://www.befundoo.com/blog/optimizing-ng-repeat-in-angularjs/) that

> An AngularJS filter in your HTML will execute (multiple times!) for
>   every digest cycle. This means that your filtering function, or your filter will execute multiple times, *even if the underlying data or conditions have not changed*

I guess the reason for it is how AngularJs works , so it needs to know (after multiple cycles) that everything is set correctly.

So basically this :

```
<div ng-repeat="stock in ctrl.stocks | filter: ctrl.searchField">
   {{stock.name}}
</div>
```

Should become this:

```
<div ng-repeat="stock in ctrl.filteredStocks">
        Pre Filtered {{stock.name}}
</div>
```

Via something like that:

```
  self.filter = function() {
        console.log(1); //for counter
        self.searchField = self.searchFieldModel;
        self.filteredStocks = filterFilter(self.stocks, self.searchField);
    };
```

As you can see - I've added `console.log` at the controller in order to see how many times this `filterStocks` are evaluated.

**Question**

For observation purpose - How can I track how many times the `filter` in :

```
<... ng-repeat="stock in ctrl.stocks | filter: ctrl.searchField">
```

is running ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/o7vbdzcw/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For observation purpose - How can I track how many times the filter in

You can track it by putting a simple `console.count` inside the filter worker...

---

Of course, if you can prefilter the array you gain performances, but considering how AngularJS works, the only way to optimize the data-binding is to use the `::` [one-time binding](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html) when you are sure that your data is immutable...
Otherwise, with the **dirty-checking** alghoritm, there are no ways to increase performaces because the diff-test is applied on each digest-cycle!

Hope helps

Comment: my question was about the filter who **is not** filtered in the controller.